# React Firebase user.email=null when login with Gmail

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have tried to access the user.email from the email input field , but it remains null

**My code :**

```
    import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import UseServiceDetails from "../Hooks/UseServiceDetails";
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import auth from "../../firebase.init";

const Checkout = () => {
  const { serviceId } = useParams();

  const [service] = UseServiceDetails(serviceId);
  // console.log(service);
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className="text-center">Please checkout  <b className="text-danger">{service.name}</b> </h2>
      <form className="w-50 mx-auto" action="">
        <input className="w-100 mb-2" type="text" value={user.displayName} name="name" placeholder=" name" readonly disabled /> <br />
        <input className="w-100 mb-2" type="text" value={user.email} name="email" placeholder="email" /> <br />
        <input className="w-100 mb-2" type="text" value={service.name} name="service" placeholder=" service" /> <br />
        <input className="w-100 mb-2" type="text" value={user.address} name="address" placeholder=" address" /> <br />
        <input className="w-100 mb-2" type="text" value={user.phone} name="phone" placeholder=" phone" /> <br />
        <button className="btn btn-danger w-50 d-block mx-auto " type="submit" value="place order">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Checkout;
```

**User in my console :**

UserImpl {providerId: 'firebase', proactiveRefresh: ProactiveRefresh, reloadUserInfo: {…}, reloadListener: null, uid: 'pFzDIqOeNyca19qJj2uOnaXoI2r1', …}
accessToken
: * removed to keep short*

auth
:
AuthImpl {app: FirebaseAppImpl, heartbeatServiceProvider: Provider, config: {…}, currentUser: UserImpl, emulatorConfig: null, …}
displayName
:
"Monzur alam"
**email
:
null**
emailVerified
:
false
isAnonymous
:
false
metadata
:
UserMetadata {createdAt: '1663568941792', lastLoginAt: '1663569399378', lastSignInTime: 'Mon, 19 Sep 2022 06:36:39 GMT', creationTime: 'Mon, 19 Sep 2022 06:29:01 GMT'}
phoneNumber
:
null

Comment: Did you add OAuth scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" as described in the docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk ?